# Android- Cannot increment a counter on first correct attempt

Tags: android, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to add mod this so that each time a player guesses the flag on the first attempt, increment a counter.  This value will then be displayed at the end when 10 flags is completed. So far i've only gotten it to display the number of guesses and correct answer percentage.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FlagQuizGame extends Activity 
{
// String used when logging error messages
private static final String TAG = "FlagQuizGame Activity";

private List<String> fileNameList; // flag file names
private List<String> quizCountriesList; // names of countries in quiz
private Map<String, Boolean> regionsMap; // which regions are enabled
private String correctAnswer; // correct country for the current flag
private int totalGuesses; // number of guesses made
private int correctAnswers; // number of correct guesses
private int guessRows; // number of rows displaying choices
private Random random; // random number generator
private Handler handler; // used to delay loading next flag
private Animation shakeAnimation; // animation for incorrect guess

private TextView answerTextView; // displays Correct! or Incorrect!
private TextView questionNumberTextView; // shows current question #
private ImageView flagImageView; // displays a flag
private TableLayout buttonTableLayout; // table of answer Buttons
private int counter;

// called when the activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call the superclass's method
  setContentView(R.layout.main); // inflate the GUI

  fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of image file names
  quizCountriesList = new ArrayList<String>(); // flags in this quiz
  regionsMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); // HashMap of regions
  guessRows = 1; // default to one row of choices
  random = new Random(); // initialize the random number generator
  handler = new Handler(); // used to perform delayed operations
  counter = 0;
  // load the shake animation that's used for incorrect answers
  shakeAnimation = 
     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.incorrect_shake); 
  shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3); // animation repeats 3 times 

  // get array of world regions from strings.xml
  String[] regionNames = 
     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.regionsList);

  // by default, countries are chosen from all regions
  for (String region : regionNames )
     regionsMap.put(region, true);

  // get references to GUI components
  questionNumberTextView = 
     (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
  flagImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagImageView);
  buttonTableLayout = 
     (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonTableLayout);
  answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

  // set questionNumberTextView's text
  questionNumberTextView.setText(
     getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " 1 " + 
     getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");

  resetQuiz(); // start a new quiz
} // end method onCreate

// set up and start the next quiz 
private void resetQuiz() 
{      
  // use the AssetManager to get the image flag 
  // file names for only the enabled regions
  AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // get the app's AssetManager
  fileNameList.clear(); // empty the list

  try 
  {
     Set<String> regions = regionsMap.keySet(); // get Set of regions

     // loop through each region
     for (String region : regions) 
     {
        if (regionsMap.get(region)) // if region is enabled
        {
           // get a list of all flag image files in this region
           String[] paths = assets.list(region);

           for (String path : paths) 
              fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
        } // end if
     } // end for
  } // end try
  catch (IOException e) 
  {
     Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names", e);
  } // end catch

  correctAnswers = 0; // reset the number of correct answers made
  totalGuesses = 0; // reset the total number of guesses the user made
  quizCountriesList.clear(); // clear prior list of quiz countries

  // add 10 random file names to the quizCountriesList
  int flagCounter = 1; 
  int numberOfFlags = fileNameList.size(); // get number of flags

  while (flagCounter <= 10) 
  {
     int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfFlags); // random index

     // get the random file name
     String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

     // if the region is enabled and it hasn't already been chosen
     if (!quizCountriesList.contains(fileName)) 
     {
        quizCountriesList.add(fileName); // add the file to the list
        ++flagCounter;
     } // end if
  } // end while

  loadNextFlag(); // start the quiz by loading the first flag
} // end method resetQuiz

// after the user guesses a correct flag, load the next flag
private void loadNextFlag() 
{
  // get file name of the next flag and remove it from the list
  String nextImageName = quizCountriesList.remove(0);
  correctAnswer = nextImageName; // update the correct answer

  answerTextView.setText(""); // clear answerTextView 

  // display the number of the current question in the quiz
  questionNumberTextView.setText(
     getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " " + 
     (correctAnswers + 1) + " " + 
     getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");

  // extract the region from the next image's name
  String region = 
     nextImageName.substring(0, nextImageName.indexOf('-'));

  // use AssetManager to load next image from assets folder
  AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // get app's AssetManager
  InputStream stream; // used to read in flag images

  try
  {
     // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next flag
     stream = assets.open(region + "/" + nextImageName + ".png");

     // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the flagImageView
     Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImageName);
     flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);                       
  } // end try
  catch (IOException e)  
  {
     Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImageName, e);
  } // end catch

  // clear prior answer Buttons from TableRows
  for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
     ((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();

  Collections.shuffle(fileNameList); // shuffle file names

  // put the correct answer at the end of fileNameList
  int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
  fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

  // get a reference to the LayoutInflater service
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  // add 3, 6, or 9 answer Buttons based on the value of guessRows
  for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) 
  {
     TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);

     // place Buttons in currentTableRow
     for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) 
     {
        // inflate guess_button.xml to create new Button
        Button newGuessButton = 
           (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, null);

        // get country name and set it as newGuessButton's text
        String fileName = fileNameList.get((row * 3) + column);
        newGuessButton.setText(getCountryName(fileName));

        // register answerButtonListener to respond to button clicks
        newGuessButton.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
        currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
     } // end for
  } // end for

  // randomly replace one Button with the correct answer
  int row = random.nextInt(guessRows); // pick random row
  int column = random.nextInt(3); // pick random column
  TableRow randomTableRow = getTableRow(row); // get the TableRow
  String countryName = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
  ((Button)randomTableRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(countryName);    
} // end method loadNextFlag

// returns the specified TableRow
private TableRow getTableRow(int row)
{
  return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
} // end method getTableRow

// parses the country flag file name and returns the country name
private String getCountryName(String name)
{
  return name.substring(name.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('_', ' ');
} // end method getCountryName

// called when the user selects an answer
private void submitGuess(Button guessButton) 
{
  String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
  String answer = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
  ++totalGuesses; // increment the number of guesses the user has made

  // if the guess is correct
  if (guess.equals(answer)) 
  {
     ++correctAnswers; // increment the number of correct answers

     // display "Correct!" in green text
     answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
     answerTextView.setTextColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));

     disableButtons(); // disable all answer Buttons

     // if the user has correctly identified 10 flags
     if (correctAnswers == 10) 
     {
        // create a new AlertDialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle(R.string.reset_quiz); // title bar string

        // set the AlertDialog's message to display game results
        builder.setMessage(String.format("%d %s, %.02f%% %s", 
           totalGuesses, getResources().getString(R.string.guesses), 
           (1000 / (double) totalGuesses), 
           getResources().getString(R.string.correct)));

        builder.setCancelable(false); 

        // add "Reset Quiz" Button                              
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                
           {                                                       
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
              {
                 resetQuiz();                                      
              } // end method onClick                              
           } // end anonymous inner class
        ); // end call to setPositiveButton

        // create AlertDialog from the Builder
        AlertDialog resetDialog = builder.create();
        resetDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
     } // end if 
     else // answer is correct but quiz is not over 
     {
        // load the next flag after a 1-second delay
        handler.postDelayed(
           new Runnable()
           { 
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                 loadNextFlag();
              }
           }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds for 1-second delay
     } // end else
  } // end if
  else // guess was incorrect  
  {
     // play the animation
     flagImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

     // display "Incorrect!" in red 
     answerTextView.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
     answerTextView.setTextColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer));
     guessButton.setEnabled(false); // disable the incorrect answer
  } // end else
} // end method submitGuess

// utility method that disables all answer Buttons 
private void disableButtons()
{
  for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); ++row)
  {
     TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
     for (int i = 0; i < tableRow.getChildCount(); ++i)
        tableRow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
  } // end outer for
} // end method disableButtons

// create constants for each menu id
private final int CHOICES_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private final int REGIONS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

// called when the user accesses the options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)             
{            
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);                        

  // add two options to the menu - "Choices" and "Regions"
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, CHOICES_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.choices);             
  menu.add(Menu.NONE, REGIONS_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.regions);             

  return true; // display the menu                        
}  // end method onCreateOptionsMenu                       

// called when the user selects an option from the menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
  // switch the menu id of the user-selected option
  switch (item.getItemId()) 
  {
     case CHOICES_MENU_ID:
        // create a list of the possible numbers of answer choices
        final String[] possibleChoices = 
           getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guessesList);

        // create a new AlertDialog Builder and set its title
        AlertDialog.Builder choicesBuilder = 
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this);         
        choicesBuilder.setTitle(R.string.choices);

        // add possibleChoices's items to the Dialog and set the 
        // behavior when one of the items is clicked
        choicesBuilder.setItems(R.array.guessesList,                    
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                    
           {                                                        
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
              {                                                     
                 // update guessRows to match the user's choice     
                 guessRows = Integer.parseInt(                      
                    possibleChoices[item].toString()) / 3;          
                 resetQuiz(); // reset the quiz                     
              } // end method onClick                               
           } // end anonymous inner class
        );  // end call to setItems                             

        // create an AlertDialog from the Builder
        AlertDialog choicesDialog = choicesBuilder.create();
        choicesDialog.show(); // show the Dialog            
        return true; 

     case REGIONS_MENU_ID:
        // get array of world regions
        final String[] regionNames = 
           regionsMap.keySet().toArray(new String[regionsMap.size()]);

        // boolean array representing whether each region is enabled
        boolean[] regionsEnabled = new boolean[regionsMap.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < regionsEnabled.length; ++i)
           regionsEnabled[i] = regionsMap.get(regionNames[i]);

        // create an AlertDialog Builder and set the dialog's title
        AlertDialog.Builder regionsBuilder =
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        regionsBuilder.setTitle(R.string.regions);

        // replace _ with space in region names for display purposes
        String[] displayNames = new String[regionNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < regionNames.length; ++i)
           displayNames[i] = regionNames[i].replace('_', ' ');

        // add displayNames to the Dialog and set the behavior
        // when one of the items is clicked
        regionsBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems( 
           displayNames, regionsEnabled,
           new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() 
           {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                 boolean isChecked) 
              {
                 // include or exclude the clicked region 
                 // depending on whether or not it's checked
                 regionsMap.put(
                    regionNames[which].toString(), isChecked);
              } // end method onClick
           } // end anonymous inner class
        ); // end call to setMultiChoiceItems

        // resets quiz when user presses the "Reset Quiz" Button
        regionsBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
           {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
              {
                 resetQuiz(); // reset the quiz
              } // end method onClick
           } // end anonymous inner class
        ); // end call to method setPositiveButton

        // create a dialog from the Builder 
        AlertDialog regionsDialog = regionsBuilder.create();
        regionsDialog.show(); // display the Dialog
        return true;
  } // end switch

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} // end method onOptionsItemSelected

// called when a guess Button is touched
private OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
     submitGuess((Button) v); // pass selected Button to submitGuess
  } // end method onClick
}; // end answerButtonListener
} // end FlagQuizGame
```

Comment: you haven't asked a specific question, and you have posted a wall of text.  You'll get a helpful response if you narrow down your code, and are clear about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry about that. My question is when the correct answer button is pressed on the first try on each question, how do I set a counter that adds this up and displays the results at the end. For example if a flag comes up and I hit the wrong answer, it wont add to the counter, because I didn't get it on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Create another variable that keeps track of the attempts on the current question. Each time the correct answer is guessed, if number of guesses = 1, increment another counter of how many answers were correctly guessed in one try. Also, after each correct answer, reset the current guesses counter back to 0.